# Is there a programming language that is just math?

Tags: linux, programming, language

I am looking for a language that would allow me to do the following

- let me write code in math notation (sort of)
- allow me to read and write memory
- write to stdin, stdout, and stderr

I am running on Arch Linux. I would like the language to be free but I am willing to pay a little.

Comment: if you need more information just tell me. No need to mindlessly downvote whilst not telling anybody how to improve

Comment: Welcome wij!  I don't currently see any downvotes on your question, but I agree.  Mindless downvoting has caused more harm on StackExchange/StackOverflow than almost anything else, in my opinion.  It's just another example of small people revealing their smallness with their actions.  I will be honoured to upvote your question if you can add information regarding OS and price requirements (or gratis) to your question and its tags.  Again, welcome!

Comment: Thank you for updating your question.  I added the `linux` tag for you.  As promised, I upvoted your question after your edit, yet someone else decided to downvote it without leaving any comment on how to improve it.  To the downvoter: **If you continue to cast downvotes without cause or willingness to help the OP improve their question, your account will be turned over to SE staff for review and possible removal**.  We are a friendly and kind community and we do not tolerate any forms of abuse or inappropriate conduct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the [CLI version of Qalculate](https://github.com/Qalculate/libqalculate) may do what you desire.

Qalculate is a cross-platform mathematics tool.  It is open-source and actively developed by the very dedicated and talented Hanna Knutsson.

The project celebrates its 20th birthday in 2023.

I have personally used both the CLI version and the GUI version.  Both are excellent and remarkably powerful.

The CLI version, although not technically a "programming language", will likely help you achieve your goals.

Comment: @wij You're welcome.  I'm glad to help you (and others who may be helped by this answer).  Qalculate is quite good.  I found it had a bit of a learning curve, but well worth it.

Answer (score 2):

[Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) is the obvious choice.  It supports a huge range of mathematical statements and has its own [Stack Exchange site](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/).

It is available on a number of platforms, including mobile.

It is not cheap, unless you are running on a Raspberry Pi, in which case it is [free](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-mathematica/) of charge.

Comment: Thanks so much for reporting that Mathematica is free on the Raspberry Pi.  I had no idea until you mentioned this.  I abandoned Mathematica a few years back due to the high cost, so this is good news.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other recommendations here I'd like to add [Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab.html).

Answer (score 1):

[Maxima](https://maxima.sourceforge.io/). It has a command line version as well as a document based interface [wxMaxima](https://wxmaxima-developers.github.io/wxmaxima/). It is free, and can be compiled from source for your version of Linux.

Answer (score 0):

[Haskell](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell) is a pure functional language that is renowned for being quite mathy.

However, when Larry Wall, the designer of the Perl language and master C hacker, calls Haskell "A Language by geniuses for geniuses" (off the top of my head, possibly slightly misquoted) then that means quite something.